# LwIP client application for Microblaze

Tags: microblaze

Does anyone have any prior experience working with LwIP running on Microblaze? My problem right now is that I'm using the info that I found on http://lwip.wikia.com/wiki/Raw/TCP to write an application to connect to an specific socket and send an array of integers, but it is not working...

Im working on a nexys 4 board and Im using Vivado IDE and Xilinx SDK to develop the application, when I load application's elf file into ram and run the application the LINK/ACT and 100/10 leds shutdown.

I wrote the application in a single .C file, I uploaded this file to:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wjlqn8nb4sfrzsb/AAAl_XB1tB6VZ7ZWIKxGQAPga?dl=0

PD: I would really appreciate if someone could give me at list a hint of what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code here. It won't help others who come across this question in the future if the link eventually breaks!

Comment: If link goes down it's not that much about C code, but rather misconfiguration of your system, you loading on FPGA. If you're making it from scratch look into MAC core being connected to proper pins. Or even better, start with working Ethernet example and continue from there.